# Web API Returns 404 When Passing Certain Encoded Special Characters

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Web API 2 with Attribute Routing to authorize users, in order to do this I am calling the method with either a plain text password (on initial login), or an encrypted password (on subsequent logins). The initial call with the plain text password works great, but the moment I try and pass through an encrypted password that contains encoded special characters it returns a 404 error code.

The moment I remove the encoded special characters (: '%3A' and + '%2B') from the password string the call works fine; I have also tried it with a much longer string than the encrypted string in order to rule out max length issues, and again it works fine.

The encoded API call is as follows:

```
https://<domain>/auth/AuthoriseUser/bob/1000%3AsK6xKXyNORYSoDbNDMnIjhLxZxReYh6ji%3AJmomj1IxqHGXXFXVJSdA5MxpkUWB1OM%2B/Android/true
```

and the attribute routing I am using is:

```
[Route("auth/AuthoriseUser/{username}/{password}/{appId}/{passwordEncrypted}")]
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: My wild guess is that you aren't url decoding the password string before you try to decrypt it/compare it to the server side encrypted password. Also, please tell me you are using https

Comment: I am definitely using https (see URL above), and I can also confirm that the call isn't actually reaching the API so it definitely isn't a decoding issue.

Comment: Just a hunch, but maybe the router is decoding the entire url before atempting to match params, and the `%3A` being a `:` would result in an invalid url, so you will get a 404. Also, is there a reason you are sending a password like this, why not the usual way as a base 64 encoded `AUTHORISATION` header?